# Get Schedule for the current day or first coming up

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I am building a scheduling app, where I assign schedules to certain members but those schedules can change at a certain date or be assigned for the future.

My database structure is like so:

```
members table:
------------------------------------
member_id


schedule table:
------------------------------------
schedule_id
schedule_name


assigned_schedules asch table:
------------------------------------
member_id
schedule_id
effective_from
effective_to
```

The `assigned_to` and `assigned_from` values are a unix timestamp. I currently have joined the tables but my where clause is quite redundant and has errors in it. I am looking to get the schedule currently assigned for the current day of a member, or the closest assigned schedule if there is one assigned in the future. A member can have a schedule assigned to a future date and it would change at that time, but I am looking for a daily view.

Currently, I join all the tables and have this where clause (where the `?` is today's timestamp):

`( asch.effective_from  <= ? AND ( asch.effective_to IS NULL OR asch.effective_to >= ? ) OR asch.effective_from IS NULL ) 
XOR 
( ( asch.effective_from > ? AND asch.effective_to IS NULL ) XOR asch.effective_from > ?  )`

`assigned_to` value can be null, which means that the schedule has no termination time.

I query the members table, and join assigned_schedules on members.member_id = assigned_schedules.member_id, and join schedule table on asiggned_schedules.schedule_id = schedule.schedule_id

Comment: Try doing it in multiple statements.  Put the member and existing schedule for today into a temp table.  Add to that the member and first available schedule for all members that are not currently in the temp table.  Select all from the temp table.

Comment: What is the type of daysAndTimes? Edit your question and show your full query, including the joins.

Comment: Also, instead of the full timestamp, which goes down to seconds (and fractional part  thereof), shouldn't you be checking for just the date part? Also, you refer to columns not shown in your tables, specifically effective_from and effective_to. Edit your question to show the full schema of each table.

Comment: @SloanThrasher daysAndTimes is data that I use from the schedule. It is a text field that holds a json_encoded array for the schedule. I parse through it in my code

Comment: @SloanThrasher Sorry, edited the table. It should be consistent effective_from and effective_to, which is start and end time of the assigned schedule for the member, respectively.

Comment: @Strawberry it seems to be adding confusion. It is just data. I removed it. It is in the schedule table. My primary concern is getting one row from assigned_schedules

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query